# How to iterate through a .txt file to create an XML

Tags: python, list, lxml

I want to create a XML file through a .txt file like this:

```
1header
2client_1
3total_1
4promo_1
5promo_1_data
2client_2
3total_1
3total_2
4promo_1
4promo_1
4promo_1
5promo_1_data
4promo_2
5promo_2_data
```

Each line begins with a specific number, that number is the id of the record type.
For example, number 2 is the id of a new client, therefore all the records that come after it belong to that summary, until the iteration gets another id 2 and creates another summary with its specific data.

That said, the desired XML output is:

```
<SummaryList>
    <Summary>
        <Client_1></Client_1>
        <Total_1></Total_1>
        <Client_Promotions>
            <Promotion>
                <Promo_1></Promo_1>
                <Promo_1_data></Promo_1_data>
            <Promotion>
        </Client_Promotions>
    </Summary>
    <Summary>
        <Client_2></Client_2>
        <Total_1></Total_1>
        <Total_2></Total_2>
        <Client_Promotions>
            <Promotion>
                <Promo_1></Promo_1>
                <Promo_1></Promo_1>
                <Promo_1></Promo_1>          
                <Promo_1_data></Promo_1_data>
            <Promotion>
            <Promotion>
                <Promo_2></Promo_2>
                <Promo_2_data></Promo_2_data>
            </Promotion>
        </Client_Promotions>
    </Summary>
</SummaryList>
```

I've been trying this:

```
filepath = 'data.txt'
lst = []
with open(filepath) as fp:
   line = fp.readline()
   while line:
       line = fp.readline()
       lst.append(line)
```

For creating a list and dividing each line into a item into that list, so I can iterate like:

```
from lxml import etree as ET
root = ET.Element('SummaryList')
root.text = '\n'
max_lines = len(lst)
line_number = 0
while line_number <= max_lines:
    if lst[line_number][0] == '2':
        a = lst[line_number]
        summary = ET.Element('Summary')
        summary.text = '\n'
        root.append(summary)
        dc = ET.Element("Client")
        dc.text = '\n'
        summary.append(dc)
        e = ET.SubElement(dc, "someClientData")
        e.text = a[1:19].strip()
        e.tail = '\n'
        dc.tail = '\n'
        totalDescount = ET.Element("Total")  # id record type 3
        totalDescount.text = '\n'
        summary.append(totalDescount)
        promoDetail  = ET.Element("ClientPromotions")  # id record type 4
        promoDetail.text = '\n'
        summary.append(promoDetail)
        summary.tail = '\n'
        
    if lst[line_number][0] == '3':
        a = lst[line_number]
        subtotal = ET.Element("SubTotal")
        subtotal.text = '\n'
        totalDescount.append(subtotal)
        e = ET.Element("description")
        e.text = a[1:101].strip()
        e.tail = '\n'
        subtotal.append(e)
        e = ET.Element("someData")
        e.text = format_money(a[101:116])
        e.tail = '\n'
        subtotal.append(e)
        subtotal.tail = '\n'
        totalDescount.tail = '\n'

    if lst[line_number][0] == '4':
        a = lst[line_number]
        promotion = ET.SubElement(promoDetail, "Promotion")  # registro 4 sub array
        promotion.text = '\n'
        promo = ET.Element("Promo")
        promo.text = '\n'
        promotion.append(promo)
        e = ET.SubElement(promo, "someClientData")
        e.text = a[1:19]
        e.tail = '\n'
        promo.tail = '\n'
        promotion.tail = '\n'
        promoDetail= '\n'

    if lst[line_number][0] == '5':
        a = lst[line_number]
        promoData = ET.Element("Promo_data")
        promoData.text = '\n'
        promotion.append(promoData)
        promoData.tail = '\n'
    line_number += 1
```

I'm creating `promoDetail` in Summary iteration, because I only need one of these tags in each Summary. But I need to create Promotion tag for every id record type 4 until it finds a id record type 5.
I'm incapable to achieve this. I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tartega/PycharmProjects/LP/test.py", line 211, in <module>
    promotion = ET.SubElement(promoDetail, "Promotion") 
TypeError: Argument '_parent' has incorrect type (expected lxml.etree._Element, got str)
```

If I add a print here:

```
if lst[line_number][0] == '4':
       a = lst[line_number]
       print(type(promoDetail))
```

I'm getting this result:

```
<class 'lxml.etree._Element'>
<class 'str'>
```

So it seems like the first iteration goes well, but the second one doesn't create this element.
Please can you help me with this? I'm newby with Python and lxml. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because you are assigning a string to `promoData` in this line:

```py
promoDetail= '\n'
```

whereas you are assuming it to be an `ET.Element` in this line:

```py
promotion = ET.SubElement(promoDetail, "Promotion")
```

From the context it looks like you meant `promoDetail.tail = '\n'`.

---

Some more tips, not directly regarding your question:

- You could use `fp.readlines()` to read the lines of `fp` into a list. If you want to get rid of the first line (which isn't actually necessary in your code snippet), you can use `fp.readlines()[1:]`.
- Since Python uses [zero-based indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering), `max_lines - 1` is the largest index for `lst` in your code. Therefore, your `while` loop only has to go on as long as `line_number < max_lines` (instead of `line_number <= max_lines).
- To iterate over items in a list while also keeping track of the item's index, you can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) (in your case, `for line_number, line in enumerate(lst)`). This way, you don't have to write `lst[line_number]` again and again.

Comment: @MemoZC Yes, your print output demonstrates the problem: First, you are assigning an `ET.Element` to `promoDetail`, and then a `str`. The first assignment is made when the line starts with a `2`, the second one (which I assumed to be a mistake) when the line starts with a `4`.

Comment: No, its not a mistake. The reason I create the element ```promoDetail``` when line starts with a ```2``` its because I only need one tag  ```promoDetail```, if I create this tag when line starts with ```4```, then I will have one for each line. That's not what I want

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was that I want to create a father tag for element starting with `4` every time that I found an element starting with `2`, so to solve this the only thing I need to do was instead of readling line by line afther finding an element `2`, I grouped the `4` and `5` into two different arrays and then I only iterate with `4` and `5` that match with the exact client on the element `2`.

```
while line_number <= max_lines:
    if lst[line_number][0] == '2':
        a = lst[line_number]
        five = []  # Only id 5 for this resume
        for i in only_fives:
            if i[168:180] in a[19:32]:
                five.append(i)
        four = []
        for i in only_fours:
            if i[19:32] in a[19:32]:
                four.append(i)
```

And this is the function to create the data into those tags 4 and 5:

```
def fours_and_fives(fours, fives, parent):
    for d2 in fives:
        PROMOTION= ET.SubElement(parent, "Promotion")
        PROMOTION.text = '\n'
        title= ET.SubElement(PROMOTION, "PromotionTitle")
        title.text = d2[1:51].strip()
        title.tail = '\n'
        for d1 in fours:
            if d1[139:189].strip() in d2[1:51].strip():
                dt = ET.SubElement(PROMOTION, "promo")
                dt.text = '\n'
                a = d1
                e = ET.SubElement(dt, "name")
                e.text = a[1:19]
                e.tail = '\n'
                e = ET.SubElement(dt, "idClient")
                e.text = a[19:32].lstrip('0')
                e.tail = '\n'
                e = ET.SubElement(dt, "card")
                e.text = a[32:52].strip()
                e.tail = '\n'
                e = ET.SubElement(dt, "lastDigits")
                e.text = a[52:56]
                e.tail = '\n'
                e = ET.SubElement(dt, "date")
                e.text = format_fecha(a[56:64])
                e.tail = '\n'
                e = ET.SubElement(dt, "nameMarket")
                e.text = a[64:114].strip()
                e.tail = '\n'
                e = ET.SubElement(dt, "coupon")
                e.text = a[114:122]
                e.tail = '\n'
                e = ET.SubElement(dt, "numberOfPayments")
                e.text = a[122:124]
                e.tail = '\n'
                e = ET.SubElement(dt, "spending")
                e.text = format_money(a[124:139])
                e.tail = '\n'
                e = ET.SubElement(dt, "promotion")
                e.text = a[139:189].strip()
                e.tail = '\n'
                e = ET.SubElement(dt, "refund")
                e.text = format_money(a[189:204])
                e.tail = '\n'
                e = ET.SubElement(dt, "thing")
                e.text = format_money(a[204:219])
                e.tail = '\n'
                e = ET.SubElement(dt, "dateRefund")
                e.text = format_fecha(a[219:227])
                e.tail = '\n'
                dt.tail = '\n'
                st = ET.SubElement(PROMOTION, "PromoSubtotal")  # Elements 5
                st.text = '\n'
                e = ET.SubElement(st, "promotion")
                e.text = d2[1:51].strip()
                e.tail = '\n'
                e = ET.SubElement(st, "description")
                e.text = d2[51:151].strip()
                e.tail = '\n'
                e = ET.SubElement(st, "spending")
                e.text = format_money(d2[151:166])
                e.tail = '\n'
                st.tail = '\n'
        PROMOCION.tail = '\n'
```

`format_money` is a function that formats a string of digits into digits with thousands dots and decimal commas.

`format_fecha` is another function that format date.